# Translation-golf and the SOLID principles

Tags: traducción, informática, translation-golf, inglés

Para esta semana voy a ofrecer un texto cuyo contexto es más moderno: los principios SOLID de programación. Según [la Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID):

> **SOLID** (*Single responsibility, Open-closed, Liskov substitution, Interface segregation and Dependency inversion*) es un acrónimo mnemónico introducido por [Robert C. Martin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Cecil_Martin) a comienzos de la década del 2000 que representa cinco principios básicos de la programación orientada a objetos y el diseño. Cuando estos principios se aplican en conjunto es más probable que un desarrollador cree un sistema que sea fácil de mantener y ampliar con el tiempo.

El primero de los principios, el de única responsabilidad, afirma que

> [...] cada módulo o clase debe tener responsabilidad sobre una sola parte de la funcionalidad proporcionada por el software y esta responsabilidad debe estar encapsulada en su totalidad por la clase.

En la Wikipedia en inglés viene un ejemplo, que es el texto cuya traducción se propone (número original de caracteres: 379):

> *Consider a module that compiles and prints a report. Imagine such a module can be changed for two reasons. First, the content of the report could change. Second, the format of the report could change. These two things change for very different causes; one substantive, and one cosmetic. The single responsibility principle says that these two aspects of the problem are really two separate responsibilities, and should therefore be in separate classes or modules.*

Traducción propuesta oculta para no condicionar (410 caracteres, ratio 1.08):

> Consideremos un módulo que compila e imprime un informe. Imaginemos que dicho módulo puede cambiar por dos motivos. El primero, que puede cambiar el contenido del informe. El segundo, que puede cambiar el formato del informe. Estos dos cambios se dan por causas muy diferentes: una sustancial y otra cosmética. El principio de única responsabilidad dice que estos dos aspectos del problema en realidad son dos responsabilidades diferentes, y por tanto deberían estar en clases o módulos separados.

¡Esto es translation-golf! [**Sigue las normas**](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/12637), pásatelo bien, aprende, y recuerda: ¡la traducción con menos caracteres que respete el original, gana!

Comment: En "chileno": 216 caracteres. Pero tuve problemas con el diccionario... _Tenís un módulo que compila y tira un informe. Cacha que el informe cambia, una, por contenido, otra, por forma. O sea por una güevá importante o por una pura güevá. Según el "principio de única responsabilidad", son güevás distintas, así que van en módulos o clases aparte._

Comment: @Rodrigo ¡no había visto esta traducción! ¡Es buenísima! Si eres capaz de argumentarla (las palabras vienen en el DLE o en el diccionario de americanismos) te la admito como respuesta. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**205 caracteres**

> Considere un módulo que genera reportes. Puede cambiar el contenido o
>   el formato, que son consideraciones distintas, una sustantiva, y la otra
>   cosmética. De acuerdo al principio de responsabilidad única, estas se
>   deben plasmar en módulos separados.

El tema del párrafo es el principio de responsabilidad única, y el ejemplo del reporte lo ejemplifica, ya que el formato y el contenido son aspectos o responsabilidades ortogonales que se deben manejar de manera separada en una aplicación correcta del diseño orientado a objetos. La expresión *"genera reportes"* es equivalente en el argot de tecnología de información (por lo menos en México) a la expresión *"compila e imprime reportes."*

Comment: ¡Gracias por participar! Por favor, añade el número de caracteres, y dado que te tomas bastantes licencias en la traducción (como eliminar frases, palabras y verbos clave), debes explicar los motivos de tales licencias. De lo contrario no podremos darla por buena.

Comment: Veo en el diccionario que "generar" significa lo mismo que "producir". Se puede considerar que esa "producción" incluye tanto la compilación como la impresión, así que la daré por buena. Del mismo modo, "clase" y "módulo" se pueden considerar sinónimos. Me chirría un poco la redacción general, que me da la sensación de que está demasiado sintetizada y me suena rara, pero voy a dar la traducción por buena.

Comment: ¡Eres el ganador de esta semana! Puedes plantear una nueva pregunta de _translation-golf_ durante las próximas 48 horas, pasado ese tiempo cualquiera podrá plantear una nueva pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

#### <s>283 270</s> 222 letras

> Dado un módulo que compila e imprime un informe, puede cambiar su contenido o su formato, por razones de peso o cosméticas respectivamente. El principio de única responsabilidad las llama responsabilidades distintas, luego pertenecerán a distintas clases o módulos.

Comentarios:

- <s>Utilizo 1º y 2º para *primero* y *segundo*.</s> Me cargo la enumeración.
- Dudé un poco en la primera parte respecto qué tipo usar, si subjuntivo (*que compile e imprima*) o indicativo (*que compila e imprime*, como uso finalmente). Como el número de caracteres es el mismo, no tiene afectación final.
- Estoy pensando en hacer caer algún *que* (*piensa se puede cambiar*...), si bien puede sonar a texto "jurídico".

Evolución:

- 222 letras: estilo mucho más directo, sin frases del tipo "esto ocurre..." o "según...".

Comment: Recuerda que, según las reglas, no se permiten las abreviaturas, por lo que 1.o y 2.o no son válidos.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo oh, se me pasó ese punto. Corregido (eliminado, vaya).

Comment: Me imaginaba que llegarías a esa conclusión. Y te he quitado una letra que te sobraba en "responsabilildades". :-D

Comment: Veo que te has picado. :-D Estas primeras pruebas parecen apuntar a que, cuanto más largo es el texto original, más se convierte esto en un concurso de síntesis más que de traducción. Tal vez debamos probar con textos más cortos en el futuro, como de 200 caracteres o menos en el original, para hacer que la gente le dé más a las neuronas.

Comment: Tal cual, síntesis es la palabra. Lo interesante es encontrar un texto bastante poco "sintentizable" para que entre en juego la búsqueda de sinónimos y expresiones raras.

Comment: Como aspirante al trono, avisarte de que he dado por buena la traducción de ixi. Puedes usar consideraciones similares para mejorar tu traducción.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo gracias por el aviso. Preferí no mirar las otras traducciones para no hacer un calco de sus ideas, así que la dejo así :) Buena segunda edición del concurso. Tal vez deberíamos poner más énfasis en mantener el sentido _y la filosofía_ de lo escrito para evitar que podemos el texto original demasiado. ¿Cómo podríamos reflejarlo en las bases?

Comment: Creo que por un lado se arreglaría proponiendo frases poco sintetizables, aunque no sé si eso haría que la traducción tuviera menos juego. Y por otro ya está estipulado que la traducción debe respetar el sentido original, y que quien pregunta tiene la última palabra. Tampoco considero necesario alargar mucho más las reglas, o corremos el riesgo de que nadie se las lea. En todo caso, cualquier propuesta que tengas podemos debatirla en la pregunta en Meta.

Comment: Parece que el ganador no inicia un nuevo juego. Como segundo clasificado, ¿te animas a proponer uno? Tienes una hora para pensarte el tema...

Comment: @CarlosAlejo acepto. Hagamos un chat rápido y te comento lo que quiero plantear, para ver si puede funcionar para corregir las debilidades que hemos encontrado.

Answer (score 2):

#### 256 characters

> Un módulo que prepara e imprime un reporte puede variar ya sea por el contenido o bien el formato.  En el primer caso, cambia la sustancia; en el segundo, lo cosmético.  El **principio de responsabilidad única** dice que estos casos son responsabilidades diferentes; por tanto deben estar en diferentes clases o módulos.

Today I was aiming for clarity of exposition and secondarily conciseness, whereas last time I was more faithful to the original.  This time I figured the important thing was the technical idea more than the style, vocabulary, etc.

**Edit**: I made some changes, partly based on feedback, partly on having digested the paragraph some more.  I used an online character counting tool -- had to subtract out the white spaces -- and then tried the TextFX plugin for Notepad++; got the same number!

Comment: I count 281 characters. See the post in Meta [Methods to easily count characters in a text](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2593/1674).

Comment: I fixed you character count, @fedorqui was right. Also, here you have some tips to improve your text and make it sound more Spanish-ish: change "sustanciosa" por "sustancial"; drop "la" in "de la responsablidad", and drop "dos" in "en dos clases" (you just need to say that they go in different classes, no need to say how many).

Comment: @fedorqui - Easily?!  (Apparently I now have another thing to add to my list of things I'm not good at -- counting characters.)

Answer (score 2):

#### 283 caracteres

> Dado un módulo que compila e imprime informes, téngase por razón para
> cambiarlo que variara el contenido o el formato de estos, por causa
> sustancial el uno y cosmética el otro. El principio de responsabilidad
> única dice que los dos aspectos supondrían, cada uno, una
> responsabilidad diferente; ergo, habrían de ocupar clases o módulos
> distintos.

Comment: Qué bueno el _ergo_

Answer (score 2):

## 223 caracteres

> Toma un módulo que compila e imprime reportes: puede cambiar porque cambia su contenido (cambio sustantivo) o su formato (cosmético). El principio de responsabilidad única dice que, al ser estas responsabilidades diferentes, deberían estar en clases o módulos distintos.

Me tomé varias licencias (sobretodo haciendo desaparecer una oración completa) pero la esencia y la semántica se conserva.

Comment: Es esa frase `Imagine such a module can be changed for two reasons.`?

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. Omito el hecho de que son dos pero los enumero (con lo cual queda claro).

Comment: Dices que te has tomado la licencia de suprimir una frase entera. Solo quería verificar cuál era. Creo que otras respuestas han hecho lo mismo. No es una recriminación ni nada parecido y aparte está en las reglas que el OP es el que juzga el mérito de la traducción. Simplemente quería verificar para que fuese más fácil comparar con el original.

Comment: Cuando el texto a traducir es largo, existe la probabilidad de que existan frases enteras que se puedan omitir al integrar lo que dicen en otras frases. En este caso, si enumeras que puede cambiar su contenido o su formato ya estás diciendo cuáles son esas dos razones. En todo caso, se pide que cuando se toman licencias se explique el motivo de las mismas en la respuesta, por si quieres ampliar la tuya con este dato. Cc: @Diego

Comment: Como aspirante al trono, avisarte de que he dado por buena la traducción de ixi. Puedes usar consideraciones similares para mejorar tu traducción.